# Big Oh and Big Omega clarification

Tags: asymptotics

Can I get an explanation of:

Can g(n) be Big O of $n^{2}$ and also the Big O of $n^{3}$? (at the same time)

Can g(n) be Big Omega of $\Omega (n)$ and also be the Big O of $n$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of Big O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question: if $g(n)=O(n^2)$, then $g(n)=O(n^{2+k})$ for all $k>0$. Indeed, $g(n)=O(n^2)$ means that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|g(n)|}{n^2}<\infty,
$$
and we also have
$$
\frac{|g(n)|}{n^{2+k}}\leq\frac{|g(n)|}{n^2}
$$
if $k>0$.

The answer to your second question is yes. After all, it is possible that $g(n)=n$.

Comment: Did you mean to put $n^{3}$ under the lim so that it's $n^{3}$ dividing $g(n)$ in order for the the limit to go on to infinity? What does the 'sup' mean?

Comment: The limit doesn't have to exist, that's why one uses the limit superior in the defintion. Or. if you want, $g(n)$ being $O(n^2)$ means that there exist $K>0$ with $|g(n)|\leq K\,n^2$ for $n$ big enough; in that case, $n^3$ would also foot the bill.